# AddThis sharing for FB and Twitter stuck in loading

Tags: addthis

So I am using the AddThiss share toolbar and followed the configurations correctly. Upon checking in storefront, The facebook and Twitter share is stuck in loading (Contacting Facebook... and Contacting Twitter...). I checked the other sites I am working on and this is also happening. I checked the addthis demo and confirmed that it is happening there as well. Is there a fix for this?

Configured and expected the FB and twitter share to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had the same issue. AddThis is shutting down as you can see on their homepage.

[Screenshot of the AddThis termination notice on the AddThis homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWRVy.jpg)

[AddToAny](https://www.addtoany.com/) is probably the best alternative, and I see they already have a [blog post](https://www.addtoany.com/blog/replace-addthis-with-addtoany-the-addthis-alternative/) and a [guide](https://www.addtoany.com/ext/addthis/) for switching to AddToAny from AddThis.